# how to customize forgetpassword controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent, laravel-controller

in my database user table doesn't have email in it , email exist in another table . so when user what to reset password i want to validate mail entered by user which means i will customize forget password controller to validate email in the other table so hoe to do that?

i get that error 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = fds@khy.com limit 1)

i tried to override sendResetLinkEmail function but no still same error
that code in forget password controller

```html
  public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|unique:user_emails,email']);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```